# Working with foreign key contraints and cascades in InnoDB/MySQL

Tags: sql, mysql, foreign-keys, innodb, cascade

I have a rather large InnoDB/MySQL relational db. I've used foreign key constraints everywhere, coupled with "ON UPDATE CASCADE" (and "ON DELETE CASCADE").

This database is part of a CRM system, and hence contains users, and then accounts are attached to those users.

Often, we discover that there are duplicate entries in the user table and we'd like to merge them.

One option is to write a script that traverses the database updating the user_id column in all dependent tables. But this will undoubtedly break every time the database structure changes.

The other option I want to explore is using the CASCADE. If I want to merge person A and person B, I can do something like this:

```
UPDATE user SET id = $A.id$ WHERE id = $B.id$ limit 1
```

Then this change should propagate through all the tables dependent on the user table.

Then I have to delete one of the the duplicate rows from user:

```
DELETE FROM user WHERE id = $A.id$ LIMIT 1
```

Unfortunately there are two problems with this approach.

Firstly, the `user.id` column is the primary key and hence unique.

Secondly (assuming I've converted `user.id` from a PRIMARY KEY to a regular INDEX), if there are duplicate IDs in user, and I delete one, then all rows from dependent tables is deleted.

Is there a way I can work around these problems?

Comment: This is confusing - you say 'user.id column is the primary key' and 'duplicate IDs in user'. If id is the primary key it is unique so how are there duplicates?

Comment: Yeah, sorry. In that second part, I'm assuming I've converted `user.id` from the primary key to a regular index. Edited.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem of merging duplicate users (Or duplicate anythings) is not something I would trust to on delete cascade and on update cascade. In the first place, how do you know which data to keep when there are conflicts (for instance two different home addresses and only one allowed)? Deduping is almost alawys best done manually from an application built for this purpose where you can choose the value that will take precedence when you hit a unique constraint. If you do it manually you need to decide the rules for determining precedence (usually the most recently updated record which means you have to record when the records were last updated). You also want to have audit tables for when you do this, so you can undo the "duplicate" that turns out not to be one.